# C# calculator application

Tags: c#, calculator

This is the code for the calculator in which i have been attempting to make. I have got it to work except i have one error that i cant seem to figure out how to fix it.

whenever the user clicks the wrong operator then clicks the correct one that they wish to use the operator (+ button - button ect)will not change to the correct one and the function carried out will be in incorrect one.

```
    double value_1 = 0;
    bool double_operation = false;
    bool clickable_decimal = true;
    bool operation_pressed = false;
    bool second_click = false;
    bool second_equals = false;
    String math_operator = "";


    private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (second_equals == true)
        {
            txt_display.Text = "0";
            //value_1 = 0;
            second_equals = false;
        }
        if ((txt_display.Text == "0") || (operation_pressed == true))
        {
            txt_display.Clear();
        }
        operation_pressed = false;
        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        txt_display.Text = txt_display.Text + btn.Text;
        double_operation = false;

    }

    private void btn_clear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txt_display.Text = "0";
        value_1 = 0;
    }

    private void btn_deci_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            if (clickable_decimal == true)
            {
                Button btn = (Button)sender;
                txt_display.Text = txt_display.Text + btn.Text;
                clickable_decimal = false;
            }

        }
    }

    private void btn_operator_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (double_operation == false)
        {
            if (second_click == false)
            {

                Button btn = (Button)sender;
                math_operator = btn.Text;
                value_1 = double.Parse(txt_display.Text);
                operation_pressed = true;
                clickable_decimal = true;
                second_equals = false;
            }

            if (second_click == true)
            {
                Button btn = (Button)sender;

                //value_2 = double.Parse(txt_display.Text);
                operation_pressed = true;
                clickable_decimal = true;

                switch (math_operator)
                {
                    case "+":
                        txt_display.Text = (value_1 + double.Parse(txt_display.Text)).ToString();
                        break;

                    case "-":
                        txt_display.Text = (value_1 - double.Parse(txt_display.Text)).ToString();
                        break;

                    case "/":
                        txt_display.Text = (value_1 / double.Parse(txt_display.Text)).ToString();
                        break;

                    case "*":
                        txt_display.Text = (value_1 * double.Parse(txt_display.Text)).ToString();
                        break;

                }//end switch
                value_1 = double.Parse(txt_display.Text);
                math_operator = btn.Text;
                second_equals = true;
            }
            second_click = true;
        }
        double_operation = true;

}

    private void btn_equals_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (second_equals == false)
        {
            switch (math_operator)
            {
                case "+":
                    txt_display.Text = (value_1 + double.Parse(txt_display.Text)).ToString();
                    break;

                case "-":
                    txt_display.Text = (value_1 - double.Parse(txt_display.Text)).ToString();
                    break;

                case "/":
                    txt_display.Text = (value_1 / double.Parse(txt_display.Text)).ToString();
                    break;

                case "*":
                    txt_display.Text = (value_1 * double.Parse(txt_display.Text)).ToString();
                    break;

            }//end switch
            value_1 = double.Parse(txt_display.Text);
            second_click = false;
            second_equals = true;
        }
```

Comment: What is the exact problem now? What have you tried? Any suggestions you have that might be the solution?

Comment: What do you mean by "clicks the wrong operator"?

Comment: Did you try debugging it? Is your "second_click == true" block getting hit when you press the button multiple times?

Comment: @doctorlove when someone clicks `+` when they meant to click `-`. So user clicks `+` then clicks `-` it will use `+` instead of `-`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `math_operator` to store the selected math operator.
Its value is only set when `second_click == false` (in `btn_operator_Click()`), therefore it seems clear why the second click doesn't change things.

Comment: i have the     `math_operator = btn.Text;`    after the switch in     `second_click == true` . Should that not set the operator?

Comment: Shouldn't it be before the switch case?

Comment: if i do that then i have to click the same operator to make it work so id have to do 5 + 6 + (11 on display) 6 - (it would minus the six as it changed operator before preforming the calculation) Doing it after fixes this

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, sorry.
Anyway, let's walk through the code and correct me if I'm wrong. 
The user clicks `+`; `double_operation` and `second_click` are false, so we'll enter the first `if` statement and `math_operator` is set; then the user realizes the mistake and clicks `-`; this time `second_click` is true, so we enter the second `if` statement; the `switch` uses `math_operator`, but that is still `+`, thus you have the wrong result.

Comment: Apologies for the confusing code i'm relatively new to coding. And yes that is correct and also it helped me realize how to fix it! thank you. I will post a response to what i changed to make it work

Comment: You're welcome, just remember to mark the question as accepted and/or upvote it if has helped you. :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer and anyone who is interested here it is.

```
    double value_1 = 0;
    bool double_operation = false;
    bool clickable_decimal = true;
    bool operation_pressed = false;
    bool second_click = false;
    bool second_equals = false;
    String math_operator = "";


    private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (second_equals == true)
        {
            txt_display.Text = "0";
            //value_1 = 0;
            second_equals = false;
        }
        if ((txt_display.Text == "0") || (operation_pressed == true))
        {
            txt_display.Clear();
        }
        operation_pressed = false;
        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        txt_display.Text = txt_display.Text + btn.Text;
        double_operation = false;

    }

    private void btn_clear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txt_display.Text = "0";
        value_1 = 0;
    }

    private void btn_deci_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            if (clickable_decimal == true)
            {
                Button btn = (Button)sender;
                txt_display.Text = txt_display.Text + btn.Text;
                clickable_decimal = false;
            }

        }
    }

    private void btn_operator_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
//==========================================================================
        if (double_operation == true)
        {
            math_operator = "";
            double_operation = false;
            second_click = false; // however it will work without this but i       
            //do not know why so ill leave it in 
        }
 // this is the solution 
 //=========================================================================
        if (double_operation == false)
        {
            if (second_click == false)
            {

                Button btn = (Button)sender;
                math_operator = btn.Text;
                value_1 = double.Parse(txt_display.Text);
                operation_pressed = true;
                clickable_decimal = true;
                second_equals = false;
            }

            if (second_click == true)
            {
                Button btn = (Button)sender;
                operation_pressed = true;
                clickable_decimal = true;
                switch (math_operator)
                {
                    case "+":
                        txt_display.Text = (value_1 + double.Parse(txt_display.Text)).ToString();
                        break;

                    case "-":
                        txt_display.Text = (value_1 - double.Parse(txt_display.Text)).ToString();
                        break;

                    case "/":
                        txt_display.Text = (value_1 / double.Parse(txt_display.Text)).ToString();
                        break;

                    case "*":
                        txt_display.Text = (value_1 * double.Parse(txt_display.Text)).ToString();
                        break;

                }//end switch
                value_1 = double.Parse(txt_display.Text);
                math_operator = btn.Text;
                second_equals = true;
            }
            second_click = true;
        }
        double_operation = true;

}

    private void btn_equals_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (second_equals == false)
        {
            switch (math_operator)
            {
                case "+":
                    txt_display.Text = (value_1 + double.Parse(txt_display.Text)).ToString();
                    break;

                case "-":
                    txt_display.Text = (value_1 - double.Parse(txt_display.Text)).ToString();
                    break;

                case "/":
                    txt_display.Text = (value_1 / double.Parse(txt_display.Text)).ToString();
                    break;

                case "*":
                    txt_display.Text = (value_1 * double.Parse(txt_display.Text)).ToString();
                    break;

            }//end switch
            value_1 = double.Parse(txt_display.Text);
            second_click = false;
            second_equals = true;
        }
```

By clicking the wrong operator it will reset the `math_operator` to equal nothing then setting `double_operation` to false so that the rest if the code below can be preformed when the user hits the correct operator.